# How can I execute a MySQL query using an array as an input instead of just a single value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of values like this:

```
[1000, 1100, 1200]
```

I want to execute a MySQL query that finds all of the entries in my database where a certain column is within a tolerance value (say +/- 1) of each of these values, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_table 
WHERE mz1_shifted
BETWEEN (1000 - 1) AND (1000 + 1)
```

Do I have to execute multiple queries, or can I instead pass in an array somehow:

```
....
BETWEEN ([1000, 1100, 1200] - 1) AND ([1000, 1100, 1200] + 1) #pseudocode
```

Comment: You could just add different `BETWEEN` clauses for each range and string them together with `OR`.  `WHERE (mz1_shifted BETWEEN (1000-1) AND (1000 +1)) OR (mz1_shifted BETWEEN (1100 - 1) AND (1100 + 1))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would OR your conditions together.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_table 
WHERE
mz1_shifted BETWEEN (1000 - 1) AND (1000 + 1)
OR
mz1_shifted BETWEEN (1100 - 1) AND (1100 + 1)
OR
mz1_shifted BETWEEN (1200 - 1) AND (1200 + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you-- is this the most efficient way? I will construct a query builder in PHP to append 'OR...' clauses if so. I thought maybe MySQL would have a built in way to deal with lists of input.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?  Efficient in terms of you writing the code?  Efficient meaning it runs quickly?

Comment: Efficient in terms of minimum execution time :-).. this will be running on tables with hundreds of millions of entries

Comment: If you want it to run quickly you need to have indexes on your columns in the WHERE clause.  See https://use-the-index-luke.com for an introduction into why indexes matter and how to use them.